# Detect taps of links/numbers in UITextView

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

theres no way to detect weather the user taped on a phone number and/or link in a UITextView is there?

There doesn't seem to be a delegate method for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant with UITextFied, but if you use a webview and get it to load a string with html tags for links, you can use the should load method to detect whats doing.